# $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}=-f'(x)$ if $f'(x)$ exist

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Suppose for $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, and  $x\in \Bbb R$, $f'(x)$ exists. How to show $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}=-f'(x)$?

**My try:** Since $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=f'(x)$, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $0<|h|<\delta$ implies $\left|\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-f'(x)\right|<\varepsilon$. Now I want to show for this $\delta$, $\left|\dfrac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}+f'(x)\right|=\left|\dfrac{f(x+(-h))-f(x)}{h}-(-f'(x))\right|<\varepsilon$ holds, but since I don't know $-f(x-h)=f(x+h)$, I can't proceed.

**Also:** Does $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}=-f'(x)$ hold for one sided derivatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}-(-f'(x))\right|=\left|\dfrac{f(x+(-h))-f(x)}{-h}-f'(x)\right|<\epsilon.
\end{align*}
The $-h$ in the second one serves as an $h$ in the $\left|\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-f'(x)\right|<\epsilon$.

Comment: So, if $0<|h|<\delta$ then $0<|-h|<\delta$, hence $\left|\dfrac{f(x+(-h))-f(x)}{-h}-f'(x)\right|<\varepsilon$, is this correct?

Comment: Thank you. What about one sided derivative? ie, for example if h approaches 0 from left only?

Comment: If $f'(x)$ exists, no matter left or right, the limit of the new one is still $f'(x)$.

Comment: But in one-sided case we can't talk about $-h$ can we? eg, $h\to+0$, we don't know behavior (or even if it is defined) at $-h$'s.

Comment: What are you assuming now? Do you assume that $f'(x)$ exists?

Comment: Yes, $f'(x)$ is one-sided derivative! I mentioned in an earlier comment!

Comment: If $f'_{+}(x)$ exists as the right (don't write $f'(x)$, this means two sided), of course, you cannot discuss about $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{+}}$ for the new one because $-h<0$.

Answer (score 3):

Simply note that for $h=-k\to 0$

$$\lim\limits_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim\limits_{k\to0}\dfrac{f(x+k)-f(x)}{-k}=-\lim\limits_{k\to0}\dfrac{f(x+k)-f(x)}{k}=-f'(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $h\mapsto -h$ is an invertible continuous map, you have
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}
=
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{-h}
$$
in the sense that one exists if and only if the other one does.

Comment: Will you please elaborate why 'invertible continuous map' allows us to do that?

Comment: @Silent Composition of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: I will be obliged if you elaborate this! I encounter this situation time after time, but I am just lost!

Comment: @Silent In this case it is really elementary: just jot down the definitions.

Comment: Also, do we use only continuity of $h\to -h$, or that of $-h\to h$, too?

Comment: @Silent They're the same function.

Comment: Oh! thank you very much.